# Using aliases in case conditions for calculation and "Then 1 else 0"

Tags: sql, count, conditional-statements, case, alias

I have query and use alias for calculation below

```
select 
 COALESCE(Clinic,'total') as Clinic,
 count(NDS) as count_NDS,
 count(Home_Care_CHSP) as count_Home_Care,
 sum(Revenue) as Revenue,
 sum(Revenue)/COUNT(NDS) as Revenue_NDS,
 sum(Revenue)/COUNT(Home_Care_CHSP) as Revenue_Home_Care
from
(
  select
    busines.label as Clinic,
    invoices.net_amount as Revenue,
    CASE 
       WHEN appoint_types.name like '%initial%' and 
       appoint_types.category IN (
        'National- ND',
        'National -ND') 
       then 1 else 0 end as NDS,
    CASE
       WHEN appoint_types.name like '%initial%' and 
       appoint_types.category IN (
        'National- Zest',
        'National-HCP') 
       then 1 ELSE 0 end as Home_Care_CHSP
  FROM 
    indiv_appoint
    INNER join appointment_types on
    appoint_types.id = indiv_appoint.appoint_type_id
    inner join invoices on
    invoices.appoint_id = indiv_appoint.id
    inner join businesses on
    busines.id = indiv_appoint.busines_id
  group by 
       busines.label,
       invoices.net_amount,
       appoint_types.name,
       appoint_types.category
)x
group by 
    ROLLUP(Clinic);
```

The Result :

```
Clinic         count_NDS   count_Home_Care   Revenue       Revenue_NDS     Revenue_Home_Care
Marli          520         520               31,815.76     61.18           61.18
Alexandria     440         440               49,273.52     111.99          111.99
total          960         960               81,089.28     173.17          173.17
```

Desire Result

```
Clinic         count_NDS   count_Home_Care   Revenue       Revenue_NDS     Revenue_Home_Care
Marli          520         763               31,815.76     61.18           41.69
Alexandria     440         512               49,273.52     111.99          96.23
total          960         1,275             81,089.28     173.17          137.92
```

Can you explain where the error is so that the values ​​become the same?

Is it in "Then else"?

The value should be different for each condition, but it seems like it only reads one condition.

Is it possible to just use one "case" and make an alias so that it can be used for calculations?

Here I add sample data and tables

**Indiv_appoint Table**

```
select DISTINCT top 5 id, busines_id, appoint_type_id from 
indiv_appoint;
id             busines_id           appoint_type_id
219,334,760    54,306               240,476
219,334,856    54,306               240,476
219,334,892    54,306               240,476
219,334,952    54,306               240,476
219,335,714    54,306               240,476
```

**Appoint_types Table**

```
select DISTINCT top 5 id, name, category from appoint_types where 
name like '%initial%' and appoint_types.category IN (
        'National- Ex Phys- Zest',
        'National- OT -HCP',
        'National- Physio -HCP',
        'National- Physio -Remedy',
        'National-Physio-TUH',
        'National- Speech Pathology- HCP');
id      name                                       category
255,041 HCP Initial (Physio/EP)                    National- Physio -HCP
339,773 HCP/CHSP OT Initial                        National- OT -HCP
360,863 CHSP Initial (Physio/EP)                   National- Physio -HCP
519,338 HCP Initial Consultation Speech Pathology  National- Speech 
                                                   Pathology- HCP
524,846 Remedy in Home Initial Assessment          National- Physio - 
                                                   Remedy
```

**Invoices Table**

```
select DISTINCT top 5 id, net_amount, busines_id, appoint_id from 
invoices;
id            net_amount    busines_id     appoint_id
75,036,772    156           54,306         167,652,727
75,036,842    75            54,295         168,391,531
75,036,914    13.1          54,306         167,652,928
75,037,029    78            54,306         167,652,897
75,037,130    24.96         54,306         160,077,399
```

**Busines Table**

```
select DISTINCT top 5 id, label from busines;
id                label
54,286            Alexandria
54,288            Harrington Park
54,289            Wetherill Park
54,306            Mobile Allied Health NSW
54,308            Marli and Moe
```

- what I want is to find the number of appointments that have '%initial% and are in the desired category from the indiv_appoint table, where is the appoint_types table (to see the appointment name and category), the invoices table (to find the total invoice value), and the busines table (to find the label)
- total net_amount (Revenue) invoices is determined based on the number of net_amount that has a category (any category as long as it is filled)
- if the number of appointments has been found by case, then calculate the total net_amount from the invoices table divided by the number of appointments from each case

Comment: Instead on `count()`, use `sum()` - count counts both 1 and 0.

Comment: @Arvo  so replace sum with count? but here I use count because I want to count the number of data, not the total value of the data. Isn't sum used to calculate the total value of the data?

Comment: Your NDS is either 1 or 0. If you have rows with 1, 0, 1, 1 - then sum() evaluates 3, count() 4 - which one you prefer? :) Sum of 0/1 values is sometimes called conditional count.

Comment: @Arvo  Yes, I use count for this condition because it takes a number of data that contains that condition, because later it will calculate revenue divided by the count of that. But when executed, returns the same value of the two conditions

Comment: Try just sum() :) Sorry, english is not my first or second language, I likely cannot explain my suggestions properly :(

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added sample data and tables, please check

Comment: @Arvo I have added sample data and tables, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ravi The following table data

```
from
indiv_appoint
INNER join appointment_types on
appoint_types.id = indiv_appoint.appoint_type_id
inner join invoices on
invoices.appoint_id = indiv_appoint.id
inner join businesses on
busines.id = indiv_appoint.busines_id
```

Comment: Don't use an answer to communicate, either write another comment, or edit your question.

Comment: @jarlh ok sorry thanks for the advice

Comment: @jarlh Do you have any input or suggestions from the above query?